# Familiars (European folklore). Looking for the right word / term in Esperanto

Tags: word-usage, culture

So, in European folklore there are supernatural entities called Familiars. Those are often mentioned in all sorts of fiction and stuff like that. But. I'm struggling to find the right word for them in Esperanto. Is it even a thing? Or I should go for some crazy construct like "konataj spiritoj" instead? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bonvenon al Esperanta diskuto ĉe Stack Exchange! Since the English term "familiar" may not be known to all, it is good add a short description what they are and provide a link to a further clarification, like to a Wikipedia article as Eduardo did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that depending on the folklore these familiars may have a non-corporal appearance (*animo, fantomo, ombro, reaperanto*), an imaginary corporal appearance (e.g. *diversaj troloj*) or they have looked like animals (e.g. *korako*).

Therefore for a general term you could pick something like *helpanto*.

Answer (score 0):

Ili estas spiritoj, kiuj diversmaniere servas familion. Oni povus difini ilin kiel helpantojn, servantojn aŭ asistantojn. Jen [la Vikipedia artikolo en la angla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familiar).

Mi pensas do ke `familia spirito` estas klara ĝenerala traduko, sed ankaŭ kompreneblus `serva/asista/helpa spirito` por tiuj kiuj scias pri kio temas, kaj depende de la kunteksto.